# Spring boot and Okta SAML2

Tags: okta, spring-security-saml2

I like the idea of using spring-security-saml2-service-provider - from of docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.0-RC1/servlet/saml2/index.html
Instead of spring-security-saml2-core it looks way less boilerplate, but I catch 400 response when I send App Embed Link from Okta admin app. Through debug it seems that

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = this.authenticationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
        if (authenticationRequest == null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);..}
```

can't resolve the incoming request,but I am not sure whether it's related.
My yml config:

```
 security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          okta:
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: http://www.okta.com/exk1juy5xrR5BsW44697
              verification.credentials:
                - certificate-location: "classpath:saml/okta.cert"
              singlesignon.url: https://trial-8410773.okta.com/app/trial-8410773_templatemanager_2/exk1juy5xrR5BsW44697/sso/saml
              singlesignon.sign-request: false
              assertingparty.metadata-uri: https://trial-8410773.okta.com/app/trial-8410773_templatemanager_2/exk1juy5xrR5BsW44697/sso/saml/metadata
```

My Okta config:

```
GENERAL
Single Sign On URLhttp://localhost:8080/api/v1/saml2/SSO
Requestable SSO URLsURLIndex
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/saml2/SSO0Recipient URLhttp://localhost:8080/api/v1/saml2/SSODestination URLhttp://localhost:8080/api/v1/saml2/SSOAudience Restrictionhttp://localhost:8080/saml/metadata
```

Also I provide endpoint for saml authentication:

```
@RequestMapping(SsoAuthenticationController.BASE_NAME)
public interface SsoAuthenticationController {

    final String BASE_NAME = "/v1/saml2/SSO";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> index( Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) ;
}
```

Actual security config:

```
http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(SECURITY_WHITELIST)
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        /*.and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)*/
        .and()
        .saml2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
```

Here is Saml interceptor's logs for google chrome:
https://pastebin.com/Be3NZe5B

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a Spring Boot 3 + SAML example with Okta recently. Hopefully, these instructions help.

Create a Spring Boot app using [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io). Select the following options:

- Project: **Gradle**
- Spring Boot: **3.0.0 (SNAPSHOT)**
- Dependencies: **Spring Web**, **Spring Security**, **Thymeleaf**

Add `src/main/java/com/example/demo/HomeController.java` to populate the authenticated user's information.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(@AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", principal.getName());
        model.addAttribute("emailAddress", principal.getFirstAttribute("email"));
        model.addAttribute("userAttributes", principal.getAttributes());
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Create a `src/main/resources/templates/home.html` file to render the user's information.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6">
<head>
    <title>Spring Boot and SAML</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>You are successfully logged in as <span sec:authentication="name"></span></p>
<p>Your email address is <span th:text="${emailAddress}"></span>.</p>
<p>Your authorities are <span sec:authentication="authorities"></span>.</p>
<h2>All Your Attributes</h2>
<dl th:each="userAttribute : ${userAttributes}">
    <dt th:text="${userAttribute.key}"></dt>
    <dd th:text="${userAttribute.value}"></dd>
</dl>

<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <button id="logout" type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Create a `src/main/resources/application.yml` file to contain your metadata URI.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
            assertingparty:
              metadata-uri: <your-metadata-uri>
```

Then, change `build.gradle` to use `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6` instead of `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` and add Spring Security SAML's dependency:

```
implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider'
```

To get the metadata URI from Okta, log in to your account and go to **Applications** > **Create App Integration**. Select **SAML 2.0** and click **Next**. Name your app something like `Spring Boot SAML` and click **Next**.

Use the following settings:

- Single sign on URL: `http://localhost:8080/login/saml2/sso/okta`
- Use this for Recipient URL and Destination URL: ✅ (the default)
- Audience URI: `http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/okta`

Then click **Next**. Select the following options:

- I'm an Okta customer adding an internal app
- This is an internal app that we have created

Select **Finish**.

Okta will create your app, and you will be redirected to its **Sign On** tab. Scroll down to the **SAML Signing Certificates** and go to **SHA-2** > **Actions** > **View IdP Metadata**. You can right-click and copy this menu item's link or open its URL. Copy the resulting link to your clipboard. It should look something like the following:

```bash
https://dev-13337.okta.com/app/<random-characters>/sso/saml/metadata
```

Go to your app's **Assignment** tab and assign access to the **Everyone** group.

Paste your metadata URI in to your `application.yml` file. Start the app using `./gradlew bootRun` and open `http://localhost:8080` in your favorite browser. You should be redirected to login.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after I switch to basic single sign on URL http://localhost:8080/login/saml2/sso/okta I catch 401, which is sort of progress for me.

Comment: Finally I catch '''Invalid assertion [id375715554935288561550335403] for SAML response [id37571555493389223699622518]: Condition '{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion}AudienceRestriction' of type 'null' in assertion 'id375715554935288561550335403' was not valid.: None of the audiences within Assertion 'id375715554935288561550335403' matched the list of valid audiances''' - which seems a bit weird cause I provided default http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/okta

Comment: I found this happened because of a request to favicon that happens first. It didn't happen for me with Firefox. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11657 for more information.

I also published a blog post today that might help: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/08/05/spring-boot-saml

Comment: Sorry for being annoying, but would it be bad practice to retrieve user from SamlResponse , create JWT to keep session stateless and pass with HttpResponse to the frontend? I watched lots of thymeleaf based manuals and information is messed hard in my head.

Comment: There's no reason to keep the session stateless. If you do all the authentication on the server-side in Spring Boot, you can use good ol' fashioned session cookies to keep the session with the client. That's what we do in JHipster (https://jhipster.tech) because it's the most secure. If you want to scale, use Redis. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/12/14/spring-session-redis